# All primes of the form $\lfloor\frac{n^2}{5}\rfloor$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

How could I find all primes of the form $\lfloor\frac{n^2}{5}\rfloor$ where n is an integer. And how can it be proven that there are no other primes? I was able to find (what I think is) all the primes, but I don't know how to prove there aren't any more.

Comment: Just a curiosity: is it a homework question?

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Let $n=5t \pm 1$.

Then note that $\lfloor\frac{n^2}{5}\rfloor=5t^2 \pm 2t=t(5t \pm 2)$

Thus, at least one of $t$ or $5t \pm 2$ has to be $1$ for $\lfloor\frac{n^2}{5}\rfloor$ to be a prime number.

You can do the same for when $n=5t,5t \pm 2$

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at. I would have to set $t$ equal to $1$, and check if $5t \pm 1$ are prime, and same for $\pm 2$ and $\pm 0$. What I'm not sure of is how to show that there aren't any other values I can use, such as $5t \pm x$, for any value $x$.

Comment: @PhilipJFry All natural numbers must have some remainder modulo 5, be that be 0,1,2,3,4. If it 1 or 4, $x=5t \pm 1$. If it is 2 or 3, $x=5t \pm 2$. If it is $0$. then $x=5t$.

Comment: I'm a little confused about where the modulus division comes in. I generalized the $\pm$ as $\pm x$, and got the expression $t(5t+2x)+\lfloor x^2/5 \rfloor$, and since $t=1$, I have $5+2x+\lfloor x^2/5 \rfloor$. What I'm getting is that $\lfloor x^2/5 \rfloor$ must be $<1$, hence x can only be 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: @PhilipJFry Let me clarify: My method is thus. The Well-Ordering Principle implies that all $n$ where $n$ is greater than $3$ is of the form $5t \pm x$, where $x$ is $0,1,2$ and $t$ is a positive integer greater than $1$. However, this implies that   $\lfloor\frac{n^2}{5}\rfloor$ is of the form $t(5t \pm x)$, were $x$ is $1$ or $2$. Notice that since $t$ is a positive integer, this implies that $5t \pm x$ is not $1$. If $t$ were greater than $1$, this would be a contradiction, since $t(5t \pm x)$ would have more than two divisors that are greater than $1$. Thus, a contradiction.

Comment: @PhilipJFry Thus, we only need to check when $t=1,0$ leaving only $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7$. Checking these manually gives that  $\lfloor\frac{n^2}{5}\rfloor$ is only prime when $n=4,5,6$.

Comment: This argument works for $\lfloor n^2/p \rfloor$ for $p=2,3,5$. It fails for $p =7$ (and larger primes) because $3^2/7 \ge 1$.

Comment: @martycohen Correct. Yet I distinctly remember I solved a problem when $p=7$.

Comment: If $n=7m+3$, $n^2/7 = (49m^2+42m+9)/7 = 7m^2+6m+9/7$ so the floor of this is prime when $7m^2+6m+1$ is prime. It usually is not but sometimes is.

Comment: @martycohen I found it! The problem had asked me to find primes that are less than a 100 of this sort when $p=7$.